# Jquery append and "for" function

Tags: jquery, for-loop, append

I've made a quiz-creator, but now I'm trying to pull out the information made in that into the "frontend" quiz.

I'm trying to build a for loop like this. And also here trying to add the class '.hide' to all the divs with class '.question-holder' except the First created one.

```
for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) 
{
    var q = questions[i];
    var answers = q.getAnswers();
    $(".question-holder").append("<h2 id='QuizQuestionHeadline'>" + q.getQuestion() + "</h2><div class='question-wrap'></div>");            
    $(".question-wrap").append("<ul class='answers' id='quiz-answers'></ul>");          

    for(var n = 0; n < answers.length; n++)
    {
        $("#quiz-answers").append("<li><input tabindex='1' type='checkbox' id='input-1'><label for='input-1'><span>"+ answers[n].getAnswer() +"</span></label></li>");          
    };
};      

for(var i = 2; i < questions.length; i++) 
{
    $(".question-holder").addClass('hide');         
};
```

Where the final HTML created by the above code should be:

```
<div class="question-holder">

<h2 id='QuizQuestionHeadline'>The Question</h2>
      <ul id='quiz-answers' class="answers">
        <li>
          <input tabindex="1" type="radio" id="input-1" name="quiz-radio">
          <label for="input-1"><span>Answer 1</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input tabindex="2" type="radio" id="input-2" name="quiz-radio" checked>
          <label for="input-2"><span>Answer 2</span></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone here that could help me out a bit? :)

Comment: Now we know what you're trying to do, what is happening instead?

Comment: Why are you putting semi-colons at the end of your for-loops?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Just by some default in my fingers I guess :)

Comment: @KevinB What's happening instead is that it is building the fronted but 1.) it doesn't put the class '.hide' to every div.question-holder except the first one. 2.) Only the first loop of answers appends, not all of them in each 'question-group'. Thing is, in the 'creator part', you can create several questions within one quiz and for each question enter some alternative answers. And in the frontend, it is supposed to go in a "slide" with question 1, question 2 and shift when you press the 'next' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're still better off hiding all the relevant divs, but then just show whichever one you want...

```
var index = 0; // 0 based, so 0 is the first question

$(".question-holder").addClass("hide");
$(".question-holder").eq(index).removeClass("hide");
```

You just need to update the `index` variable and run that code again to show a specific question :)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `$(".question-holder").addClass('hide');` will hide all divs with class `question-holder`. So for loop doesn't make any sense here.

```
for(var i = 2; i < questions.length; i++) {
    $(".question-holder").addClass('hide');         
};
```

You can do it using different id for each div and then use this addClasshide to all divs except the 1st one.

---

Another simple solution is:

first hide all divs and then show the 1st row as code shown below.

```
$(".question-holder").css('display', 'none');
$(".question-holder:first").css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try making IncrementID for the questions.

Comment: Another simple solution is:
first hide all divs and then show the 1st row as code shown below.
$(".question-holder").css('display', 'none');
$(".question-holder:first").css('display', 'block');

Comment: I have added another simple solution if you just need to show 1st div ;)